# Nuxt: how do I access axios within the fetch() method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt and am looking for a way to access the `axios` object from within the nuxt `fetch()` method. Unfortunately I can't seem to access it. This is what I've tried...

```
    async fetch({store, params}) {
        // const result = await axios.$get('/api/v2/inventory/3906?apiKey=xxx');
        // const result = await this.axios.$get('/api/v2/inventory/3906?apiKey=xxx');
        // const result = await $axios.$get('/api/v2/inventory/3906?apiKey=xxx');
        store.commit('property/setProperty', result);
    }
```

`this` is (obviously) not available and `$axios` and `axios` are undefined.

I do have `@nuxtjs/axios` defined in my `nuxt.config.js`

```
modules: [
    'nuxt-buefy',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
    '@nuxtjs/device',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
],
```

Comment: but [the docs show](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/) that you actually have access to it ... you can simply import it, and what I normally do is append to the build config under vendors, like https://i.imgur.com/KluUrUk.png that way I can easily use `import axios from 'axios'` or if possible `this.$axios...`

Comment: @balexandre I was missing a simple 'import axios from 'axios', ha ha ha. If you make that an actual answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: it's just easy if you delete the question :) it's an awful easy answer :D or... answer yourself, and mark it as accepted in a few days ;)

Comment: Ha ha. I think this is a useful answer. I'll take the points gift. Thanks. Ha ha!

Comment: if you mark your own answer correct, for your own question, you get no points :P - I've upvoted anyway :P ... P.S. I'm also new to Nuxt ... I'm using [Program with Erik](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCshZ3rdoCLjDYuTR_RBubzw/search?query=nuxt) a lot to know this great VueJs framework helper :)

Answer (score 1):

@balexandre should actually get the credit for this. Thanks for the help.

This is an incredibly stupid question I asked, but I'm going to post the answer here in case anyone else has the same experience brain-fart.

```
import axios from 'axios' // don't forget me!

... later...

fetch() {
  async fetch({store, params}) {
    const result = await axios.get('/api/v2/inventory/3906?apiKey=xxx');
    store.commit('property/setProperty', result);
  }
}
```

Comment: In case of ssr mode this is wrong method because it leads to memory leaks. It is necessary to install https://axios.nuxtjs.org/ and use `this.$axios.$get(url)`